# Limit of sequence via limit of function

Tags: limits, functions

I need to calculate this limit:
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}p^n(n+1)\\$ for $0<p<1$. I haven't got any idea for it, but can I calculate a limit for function:

$f(x)=p^x(x+1)\\
0<p<1\implies p=1/q, 1<q$

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{x+1}{q^x}=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{(x+1)'}{(q^x)'}=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{q^x\ln{q}}=0$

And then say that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0 \implies \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(n)=0?$

Or maybe there is another way to find the limit?

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

You can also use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p^{n+1}(n+2)}{p^n(n+1)}=p.$$So, take some $q\in(p,1)$ and take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies\frac{p^{n+1}(n+2)}{p^n(n+1)}<q$. Then, if $n>N$,\begin{align}p^n(n+1)&=\frac{p^n(n+1)}{p^{n-1}n}\times\frac{p^{n-1}n}{p^{n-2}(n-1)}\times\cdots\times\frac{p^{N+1}(N+2)}{p^N(N+1)}p^N(N+1)\\&<q^{n-N}p^N(N+1).\end{align}So, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}q^{n-N}p^N(N+1)=0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}p^n(n+1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another elementary way to calculate the limit:

- $0<p<1 \Rightarrow p = \frac{1}{1+h}$ for some $h>0$

Now, using the binomial formula for $(1+h)^n$ you get for $n\geq 2$:

- $\frac{1}{(1+h)^n} < \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}h^2}$

Putting this together yields:
$$0\leq p^n(n+1)= \frac{n+1}{(1+h)^n}<\frac{2}{h^2}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n(n-1)}\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$